# Need help on Flexible search query to retrieve the classification atrributes values matches with one of the classification attribute

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, flexible-search

Iam new to Flexible Search Query, I am trying to write flexible search query to retrieve the classification atrributes values matches with one of the classification attribute as below:

```
select {ca.code} from {ProductFeature as pf 
join Product as p on {pf.product} = {p.pk} 
join ClassAttributeAssignment as caa on {pf.classificationAttributeAssignment} = {caa.pk}
join ClassificationAttribute as ca on {caa.classificationAttribute} =  {ca.pk}
join ClassificationClass as cc on {caa.classificationClass} = {cc.pk}
JOIN CatalogVersion as cv ON {cv.pk}={p.catalogVersion}
 JOIN Catalog as cat ON {cat.pk}={cv.catalog}} where {ca.code} = 'capacity' and {cv.version} = 'Staged'
```

In above snippet, am able to get code of ClassficationAttribute, but how do I get values of that attribute?

Comment: The values are stored in ProductFeature. Try adding {pf.value} or {pf.rawvalue} to see them. You already seem to have the required join. Could be that you need another join between ProductFeature and the ClassificationAttribute though. Not sure

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. The problem is that your select statement is wrong.
You need to be using `{pf.stringValue}` instead of `{ca.code}`